# How to return values after deleting relationship in neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

How can I return the values of nodes and relationships after deleting a relationship

*Cypher:*

```
MATCH (p:Person)-[t:LIKED]->(a:Post) WHERE p.identity='kOo08cpMoYPWwnwB4XMZ3CbTRcO2' AND a.uuid='b60f773d-6d85-48bc-9900-8037c4b2c0b2' DELETE t WITH p,a MATCH (a)<-[l:LIKED]-() RETURN count(l) AS likes, exists((p)-[:LIKED]->(a)) AS liked, a.uuid AS uuid
```

the above query always returns `[]` , *p* and *a* nodes do exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the second `MATCH` doesn't find any matches. Try to use the [`OPTIONAL MATCH`](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/optional-match/) statement:

```
MATCH (p:Person)-[t:LIKED]->(a:Post)
WHERE p.identity='kOo08cpMoYPWwnwB4XMZ3CbTRcO2' AND a.uuid='b60f773d-6d85-48bc-9900-8037c4b2c0b2'
DELETE t
WITH p,a
OPTIONAL MATCH (a)<-[l:LIKED]-()
RETURN count(l) AS likes, exists((p)-[:LIKED]->(a)) AS liked, a.uuid AS uuid
```

Comment: so `MATCH` doesn't return when it is empty?

Comment: Cypher operations execute per row. If there is no row to execute upon, then nothing will happen. Your MATCH failed to find a pattern, therefore the row is filtered out. If you use an OPTIONAL MATCH, the row will never be filtered out, but when the pattern isn't found any newly-introduced variables will be `null` instead. Here's the [OPTIONAL MATCH](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/optional-match/) documentation.